# UISlider as audio seekbar jumping to maximum value when changed

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

I am using a `UISlider` as a seek bar for audio and it works great for adjusting to change position in the track if it is not animated. If it's animated it works great and tracks along the bar in time with the track perfectly but if you try and adjust it while the animation is active, it jumps to the maximum value of the bar. I assume there is a conflict between the two processes but I'm struggling to work out a fix.

```
func changeProgressBar() {
    let trackLength = Float(AudioService.shared.playerItem?.duration.seconds ?? 0)

    Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.5, repeats: true){_ in
        let currentTime = Float(AudioService.shared.player?.currentTime().seconds ?? 0)
           let sliderPosition = currentTime / (trackLength / 100)

           self.progressBar.setValue(sliderPosition, animated: true)
           print("the current time is", currentTime)
           print("the slider position is", sliderPosition)
    }
}

@IBAction func progressBarValueChanged(_ sender: UISlider) {
    let trackLength = AudioService.shared.playerItem?.duration.seconds ?? 0
    let sliderValueFloat = progressBar.value * 100.00
    let sliderValueDouble = Double(sliderValueFloat)
    let targetTime = (trackLength / 100 * sliderValueDouble)
    let targetTimeActual = CMTimeMake(value: Int64(targetTime), timescale: 1)
    AudioService.shared.player!.seek(to: targetTimeActual)
}
```

I have buttons that add or subtract 30 seconds to skip forward or back in the track and they work fine even when the animation is active.

```
@IBAction func plus30Secs(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let currentTime = Float(AudioService.shared.player?.currentTime().seconds ?? 0)
    let seekTime = currentTime + 30
    let seekTimeActual = CMTimeMake(value: Int64(seekTime), timescale: 1)
    AudioService.shared.player!.seek(to: seekTimeActual)
}

@IBAction func minus30Secs(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let currentTime = Float(AudioService.shared.player?.currentTime().seconds ?? 0)
    let seekTime = currentTime - 30
    let seekTimeActual = CMTimeMake(value: Int64(seekTime), timescale: 1)
    AudioService.shared.player!.seek(to: seekTimeActual)
}
```

Comment: You might wanna change the slider values inside `DispatchQueue.main.async`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, i have fixed it.

The issue was i had `progressBar.maximumValue = 100` meaning that my `progressBar.value * 100.00` was giving a value 100 times what it should have been and as such a value beyond the end of the track. I removed the `* 100.00` and now it works great.